# How to disable prepared statements in typeorm

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, typeorm

I am using typeorm, AWS lambda, RDS database proxy and an RDS postgress DB.

The RDS proxy pins the session because typeorm uses prepared statements. In the proxy log file I see the following:

`2022-03-01T05:06:02.450Z [WARN] [proxyEndpoint=default] [clientConnection=3686999430] The client session was pinned to the database connection [dbConnection=1882299696] for the remainder of the session. The proxy can't reuse this connection until the session ends. Reason: A parse message was detected.`

Is there a way to configure/modify typeorm so that it doesn't use prepared statements?

If the RDS proxy session pins every connection because typeorm has to use prepared statements, is there any benefit to using the RDS proxy?

Thx

Comment: Hav you been able t figure this out? and what if you close the connection? will the session still pinned?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues but with python, and I just fixed it.

The `WARN` message I got from the PostgreSQL RDS proxy log.

```
2023-03-09T00:25:15.845Z [WARN] [proxyEndpoint=default] [clientConnection=2188738432] 
The client session was pinned to the database connection [dbConnection=2276413833] for the remainder of the session. 
The proxy can't reuse this connection until the session ends. 
Reason: A parse message was detected.
```

AWS documents list the reason for postgres proxy pinning
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy-managing.html#rds-proxy-pinning, one of the reasons is `Prepared Statements`

```
Using prepared statements, setting parameters, or resetting a parameter to its default
```

Looking back my lambda code, the reason why I got `connection pinning` is because the library I use `pg8000` for PostgreSQL always uses **Prepared Statements**

1. [pg8000-API-Prepared-Statement](https://pypi.org/project/pg8000/#prepared-statements)
2. [pg8000-psycopg2-difference](https://groups.google.com/g/web2py/c/gSDIqQHSAD4/m/TWcaqwGheo0J)
3. [pg8000-prepare-statement](https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000/issues/132#issuecomment-274737308)

So I change the lib instead of using `pg8000`, I used `psycopg2`, then it worked, `no connection pinning` anymore.

Also, just in case you don't want to build the `psycopg2` library, there has a python layer that can be used right away.

https://github.com/jetbridge/psycopg2-lambda-layer

I hope this can give people some idea or direction who have this issue in their debugging.